# How to seed utcnow() for EF Core and Postgres

Tags: postgresql, datetime, entity-framework-core

I am trying to seed some values for a `DateTime` property in EF Core. Currently, it is seeding `DateTime.Now` with the following code

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AnalysisFile>()
                .Property(analysisFile => analysisFile.TimeCreated)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("now()");
```

So `now()` is basically a native Postgres method that is doing the magic here. I searched online and also looked at the Postgres documentation to see if there is a function that gives me something like `utcnow()`.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

I was not able to find anything like that. Maybe that functionality does not exist in Postgres. Then I started wondering if there is any way to specify timezone in conjunction with `HasDefaultValueSql. I did not find much help there as well.

Am I missing something here? I thought this would be straightforward but I am not able to find any functionality in either EF Core or Postgres that does it natively. Any suggestions?

Comment: How about `timezone('UTC', now())`?

Answer (score 1):

I created a constants file.

```
public static class SqlKeyWords
{
    public const string CurrentUserDefault = "CURRENT_USER"; /* SqlServer, PostGres */

    //public const string CurrentTimeStamp = "GETUTCDATE()"; /* SqlServer */

    public const string CurrentTimeStamp = "timezone('utc', now())"; /* PostGres */ 
}
```

and then I refer to that [single source of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth) in my "Map":

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace MyCompany.MyEfLayer.OrmMaps
{
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    public class MyThingMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyThingEntity>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyThingEntity> builder)
        {


            builder.Property(cn => cn.LastUpdated).HasColumnName("LastUpdatedColumn");
            builder.Property(dvsql => dvsql.LastUpdated).HasDefaultValueSql(SqlKeyWords.CurrentTimeStamp);
            builder.Property(req => req.LastUpdated).IsRequired();

        }
    }
}
```